# Supress Powershell banner that appears when workflow executes?

Tags: powershell, workflow

I am running a workflow from within a Powershell script. When the workflow is invoked, I get this blue banner, which is unfortunately temporarily covering up useful text output from the calling script. I created this script as a test:

```
workflow foobar {
Param ($MountedDrives)
powershell -command C:\users\admin\desktop\Foobar2.ps1 $MountedDrives
}
$mountedDrives="D:"
foobar $mountedDrives
```

[image]

Is there any way to suppress the blue banner altogether? I have tried invoking the workflow with

```
workflow foobar {
powershell -windowstyle hidden -command foobar2.ps1
}
```

and also

```
workflow foobar {
powershell -nologo -command foobar2.ps1
}
```

Both execute the workflow but display the banner.

Comment: Have you tried to set the `$ProgressPreference` to `SilentlyContinue`?

Comment: That seems to have done the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Olaf mentioned in the comments, the solution is to add

```
$ProgressPreference='SilentlyContinue'
```

Thus:

```
workflow foobar {
  Param ($MountedDrives)
  $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
  powershell -command C:\users\admin\desktop\Foobar2.ps1 $MountedDrives
}
$mountedDrives = 'D:'
foobar $mountedDrives
```